# Chromadepth3D shader in three.js

Tags: webgl, three.js, javascript-framework

What do i have to change in these two vertexshader/fragmentshader to make it work in three.js? Or is it possible to change 'MeshDepthMaterial' to display the chromadepth color scheme?

```
**The vertex shader looks like this:**


varying vec3 MCposition;
varying float LightIntensity; 
varying float Z;


void
main( void )
{
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

    vec3 tnorm      = normalize( vec3( gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal ) );
    vec3 LightPos   = vec3( -2., 0., 10. );
    vec3 ECposition = vec3( gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex );
    Z = ECposition.z;
    LightIntensity  = dot( normalize(LightPos - ECposition), tnorm );
    LightIntensity = abs( LightIntensity );

    MCposition  = gl_Vertex.xyz;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}


**The fragment shader looks like this:**


varying vec3 MCposition;
varying float LightIntensity; 
varying float Z;

uniform float Ad;
uniform float Bd;
uniform float NoiseAmp;
uniform float NoiseFreq;
uniform float Alpha;
uniform float Tol;
uniform sampler3D Noise3;
uniform float ChromaBlue;
uniform float ChromaRed;
uniform float Blend;

const vec3 BEAVER = vec3( 1., .5, 0. );
const vec3 WHITE  = vec3( 1., 1., 1.);

// return 0. if < left-tol or > right+tol
// return 1. if >= left+tol and <= right-tol
// else blend

float
Pulse( float value, float left, float right, float tol )
{
    float t = (  smoothstep( left-tol, left+tol, value )  -  smoothstep( right-tol, right+tol, value )  );
    return t;
}

vec3
ChromaDepth( float t )
{
    t = clamp( t, 0., 1. );

    float r = 1.;
    float g = 0.0;
    float b = 1.  -  6. * ( t - (5./6.) );

        if( t <= (5./6.) )
        {
                r = 6. * ( t - (4./6.) );
                g = 0.;
                b = 1.;
        }

        if( t <= (4./6.) )
        {
                r = 0.;
                g = 1.  -  6. * ( t - (3./6.) );
                b = 1.;
        }

        if( t <= (3./6.) )
        {
                r = 0.;
                g = 1.;
                b = 6. * ( t - (2./6.) );
        }

        if( t <= (2./6.) )
        {
                r = 1.  -  6. * ( t - (1./6.) );
                g = 1.;
                b = 0.;
        }

        if( t <= (1./6.) )
        {
                r = 1.;
                g = 6. * t;
        }

    return vec3( r, g, b );
}


void
main( void )
{
    vec4  noisevec  = texture3D( Noise3, NoiseFreq*MCposition );
    float n = noisevec[0] + noisevec[1] + noisevec[2] + noisevec[3];    // 1. -> 3.
    // n = ( n - 1. ) / 2.;         // 0. -> 1.
    n = ( n - 2. );             // -1. -> 1.

    vec2 st = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
    st.s *= 2.;

    float Ar = Ad/2.;
    float Br = Bd/2.;

    int numinu = int( st.s / Ad );
    int numinv = int( st.t / Bd );

    vec3 TheColor = WHITE;
    float alfa = 1.;

    st.s -= float(numinu) * Ad;
    st.t -= float(numinv) * Bd;
    vec3 upvp =  vec3( st, 0. );
    vec3 cntr =  vec3( Ar, Br, 0. );
    vec3 delta = upvp - cntr;
    float oldrad = length( delta );
    float newrad = oldrad + NoiseAmp*n;
    delta = delta * newrad / oldrad;
    float du = delta.x/Ar;
    float dv = delta.y/Br;
    float d = du*du + dv*dv;
    if( abs( d - 1. ) <= Tol )
    {
        float t = smoothstep( 1.-Tol, 1.+Tol, d );
        TheColor = mix( BEAVER, WHITE, t );
        //alfa =     mix( 1., 0., t );
    }
    if( d <= 1.-Tol )
    {
        TheColor = BEAVER;
    }
    if( d >= 1.+Tol )
    {
        alfa = Alpha;
        if( alfa == 0. )
            discard;
    }

    float t = (2./3.) * ( Z - ChromaRed ) / ( ChromaBlue - ChromaRed );
    t = clamp( t, 0., 2./3. );
    vec3 rgb = ChromaDepth( t );
    TheColor = mix( TheColor, rgb, Blend );

    gl_FragColor = vec4( LightIntensity*TheColor, alfa );
}
```

...or is this version easier to implement:

```
    ** vertex shader **

    varying float depth;
    varying float lighting;
    varying float specular;


    #define NEAR 10.0
    #define FAR 20.0

    void main()
    {   

        gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
        gl_Position = ftransform();


        float ambient = length(gl_FrontMaterial.ambient.rgb * gl_LightModel.ambient.rgb);

        vec3 normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
        vec3 light = normalize(vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position));
        float diffuse = length(max(dot(normal,light),0.0) * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse
          * gl_LightSource[0].diffuse);

        lighting = diffuse + ambient;

        specular = length(pow(max(dot(normal, gl_LightSource[0].halfVector.xyz),0.0)
          ,gl_FrontMaterial.shininess) * gl_LightSource[0].specular.rgb * gl_FrontMaterial.specular.rgb);


        depth = clamp((gl_Position.z-NEAR)/FAR,0.0,1.0);
    }

**fragment shader**

uniform sampler2D diffusemap;
varying float depth;
varying float lighting;
varying float specular;

void main (void)
{
    vec4 rgb;
    float depth2 = depth*depth;
    if (depth < 0.5) {
        rgb.g = 1.6*depth2+1.2*depth;
    } else {
        rgb.g = 3.2*depth2-6.8*depth+3.6;
        rgb.b = depth2*-4.8+9.2*depth-3.4;
    }
    depth = depth/0.9;
    depth2 = depth2/0.81;
    rgb.r = -2.14*depth2*depth2 -1.07*depth2*depth + 0.133*depth2 +0.0667*depth +1.0;

    float texval = length(texture2D(diffusemap,gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb)/2.0 + 0.5;
    gl_FragColor = rgb*(texval*lighting + specular);
}---
```

> [This Image is an Example how it should look like. Source was DepthShader-Material - colorized in Photoshop](http://www.abload.de/img/depthmap_chromadepthx2qs8.png)